# How to Enable the MiniMap extension and what is it?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm interested to use the minimap extension but i find that there is no documentation.
here is the question i want to know:
What is the minimap extenstion?
what is the requirement to use it?

I've tried to load the extension by running viewer v7.1 and its stop by can't get the DocumentNode.

```
var optionObject = {
      extensions: ['Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension']
    };
    var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv, optionObject);
```

```
NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode()
```

NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode() is return null, the minimap didn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be in first person walking mode for the minimap to show up:
[image]

And `getDocumentNode()` will only return the current view object if the model is loaded using `loadDocumentNode`, e.g.:

```
NOP_VIEWER.loadDocumentNode(doc,doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry())
```

Comment: Also, make sure to generate the AEC levels meta-data when you generate the SVF/bubble.  This extensions needs to know the ceiling and floor height, to render the 2D floor-plan view.

To do that, add the 'advanced' option in your POST job request.  Here are the step-by-step instructions:  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces