# Minimap do not show 2D view

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689542/how-to-enable-the-minimap-extension-and-what-is-it) tuttorial to load the **Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension** to my viewer, but can not see the 2D plan view on the minimap. I'm also try to set generateMasterViews to true in the option of translation process but nothing better.
Can you please help ? Thank in advance.

```
   formats: [
      {
        type: "svf",
        views: ["2d", "3d"],
        advanced: {
            "generateMasterViews": true
          }
      }
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: When you translate the model again with `generateMasterViews` set to true did you use the same bucket object? If so did you force re-generate the derivatives with `x-ads-force` flipped to true as well[see here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers)? Otherwise the AEC meta data is not going to get generated.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I'm not translate the model again but upload it to the new bucket with the new model and translate with  the setting as you said. Nothing seem better, at the beginning it only show up small icon like the image i attached but when i moving then it go away.

Comment: Perhaps somehow the AEC data did not get generated properly - can you upload the offending model to Dropbox/GDrive etc if possible and drop the link to us at forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to access the 2D view in the minimap you need to have the AEC data. after loading the document you must download the AECdata through the downloadAecModelData () method.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
  var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
  viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
  viewerDocument.downloadAecModelData();
}
```